# ASP.Net MVC 4 Razor - Paging through search results on webgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have created a search page which returns a list of objects to be displayed on a webgrid. I am using the webgrids default paging. The problem arises when I try to page to the second page of search results - I am taken back to the search page. How do I use the deafult paging functionality of the razor webgrid and achieve paging through search results ?

Actionmethod :

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetEmails(UserResponse response )
    {
        if (response.RefId != null)
        {
            int refID = Convert.ToInt32(response.RefType);
            var query = from c in db.tb_EmailQueue
                        where c.ReferenceTypeId == refID && c.ReferenceId.Contains(response.RefId)
                        select c;

            var results = new List<tb_EmailQueue>();

            results.AddRange(query);

            return View("Index", results);
        }
      return View();

      }
```

Search Page View :

```
    <body>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
         {
           @Html.DropDownListFor(x=> x.RefType, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)  ViewBag.Categories,"Please select reference type") 

    <br/>

    <p>Reference Type</p>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.RefId)
 <input type ="submit" value="Submit" />

}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Date, new{@id="example1"})
    <input type ="submit" value="Submit" />
    <br/>

}
```

Results Display View :

```
    @{
if (Model.Any())
{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 100);


    @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table table-striped table-bordered", columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column(header: "EmailQueueId",
                    columnName: "EmailQueueId",
                    format: item => Html.ActionLink(((int) item.EmailQueueId).ToString(), "Details", new {id = item.EmailQueueId})),
        grid.Column("QueueDateTime", canSort: true, format: @<text>@item.QueueDateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yy H:mm:ss")</text>),
        grid.Column("ReferenceTypeID"),
        grid.Column("ReferenceID"),
        grid.Column(header: "ToList",
                    columnName: "ToList",
                    format: @<input type ="text" value="@item.ToList"  title="@item.ToList" readonly="readonly"/>),
        grid.Column(header: "Subject",
                    columnName: "Subject",
                    format: @<input type ="text" value="@item.Subject" title ="@item.Subject" readonly="readonly"/>),
        grid.Column("FailureCount")
                                                                        ))
}

else
{
    <p>No records</p>
}
}
```

Comment: I haven't used `WebGrid` before, so I'll try to get the information I'm missing here. When you click for the "Next Page", it calls the `GetEmails` method, correct? Somewhere in the call to the method, it should be sending at least what page number you're looking for, and hopefully the number of results per page. Are you seeing this information?

Comment: The webgrid sends that back normally

Answer (score 0):

Since you get back what page number being asked for, and you know how many results you're looking for, you're just missing a piece to your LINQ query. I don't use the SQL syntax, so please excuse this, though it should be easily translatable to your methodology.

```
var query = (from c in db.tb_EmailQueue
            where c.ReferenceTypeId == refID && c.ReferenceId.Contains(response.RefId)
            select c).Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

You want `(pageNumber - 1)` because your `pageNumber` will be 1-based, and if you're looking for the first page, you don't want to skip anything `(0 * pageSize)`. With those results, you just want to `Take()` however many are going to be displayed on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of paging and sorting with WebGrid a filtered subset of a table has been solved for the ASP.NET Web Pages framework by Mike Brind in this article: [Displaying Search Results In A WebGrid](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/180/Displaying-Search-Results-In-A-WebGrid).

I have tried to translate it in MVC, but I am more comfortable with Web Pages, so be tolerant.

*Controller*

```
public ActionResult Customers(string country)
{
    var search = (country == null ? "" : country);
    NORTHWNDEntities db = new NORTHWNDEntities();
    var query = from c in db.Customers
                where c.Country.Contains(search)
                select c;
    var results = new List<Customers>();
    results.AddRange(query);

    return View("Customers", results);
}
```

*View*

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, rowsPerPage:5);
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>Customers</h1>
</hgroup>

<section id="searchForm">
    @using (Html.BeginForm()){
        <p>
            Country: @Html.TextBox("Country", @Request["Country"]) 
            <input type="submit" />
        </p>
    }
</section>
<section>
    <div>
        @grid.GetHtml(columns:grid.Columns(
            grid.Column(columnName:"CompanyName",header:"Name"),
            grid.Column(columnName:"Address"),
            grid.Column(columnName:"City"),
            grid.Column(columnName:"Country")
        ))
    </div>
</section>

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
       $('th a, tfoot a').on('click', function () {
            $('form').attr('action', $(this).attr('href')).submit();
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
}
```

I have used the Northwind sample db; if you want to use my same db, you can find it at [this link](http://businessimpactinc.com/install-northwind-database/).

The solution keeps the search form and the WebGrid in the same page, because every time you change pagination or sort order, you must repost the search criteria to filter the table.

According with Mike Brind, "*The answer to the problem lies in the snippet of jQuery that appears in the script section. A handler is attached to the onclick event of the links in the table head and table foot areas - or the sorting and paging links. When they are clicked, the value of the link is obtained and provided to the form's action attribute, then the form is submitted using POST, and the GET request is cancelled by return false. This ensures that paging and sorting information is preserved in the Request.QueryString collection, while any form field values are passed in the Request.Form collection.*"